# How to use Spanish characters in Handlebars templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I am wondering what the idiomatic way to render special language characters is using Handlebars.js templates. When I render the normal html I can use something like the Spanish lowercase e, &#233, and it renders as expected. When I pass the same text as a string to my Handlebars template I just see the characters &#233.

I have tried creating a Handlebars helper that used jquery to render the text using .html() then returning the .html() of the tmp element and I get the same results.

Comment: probably your web server is not configured to use UTF-8 chars OR serves pages with a iso-8859-x which doesn't contain `&#233` OR there's a double encoding for the & somewhere

Comment: but then wouldn't it prevent normal rendering from working as expected? If I put the `&#233` in an html tag it renders correctly. It just has issues when rendering through handlebars.js

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you try outputting your content as HTML. You can do this by adding triple brackets in your handlebars template.

```
<div class="entry">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <div class="body">
    {{{body}}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it could happen because you have written you partials with an editor that encode the characters in ANSI, and then, the rendering of the layout is set to display in utf8:

Al least it is what have brought me crazy until I saw the editor encoded the typical acented spanish vowels éíóúá... in ANSI and the layout was set to UTF8. With Notepad++ you see what is the encoding of any file very easy, if you open the file and you look at the menu Codification.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic but  I stumbled across it while having a similar issue with French characters. Any hard-typed HTML, the {{{body}}} wasn't working.

I solved this on the handlebars call:

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="./js/handlebars-v4.1.0.js"></script>
```

The `charset="utf-8"` forces handlebars to generate an output in `utf-8` encoding. This resolved all French characters on the entire page (including hard-typed content) and didn't break anything.